# О буквах и знаках русского языка

Tags: орфография

Мне не нравилось посещать школу уже потому, что я чувствовал себя дураком среди одноклассников. Например, мои одноклассники называли символ "ь" (мягкий знак) буквой, а я полагал, что символ "ь" (мягкий знак) не является буквой. В связи с этим, шкрабиха (школьная работница) шипела на меня: "Все нормальные дети понимают, что мягкий знак - буква, а этот не понимает".

Дополнение (от 15.06.2014)

Однажды, сокрушаясь от своей неспособности "быть как все", я пришёл на занятие к своему учителю музыки. Он взглянул на меня и спросил: "Что-нибудь случилось?" Я сознался, что никак не могу понять, почему мягкий знак следует считать буквой. Николай Константинович улыбнулся и сказал: "Если мягкий знак - буква, тогда бемоль - нота."

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что ваше сообщение о буквах и знаках в действительности поднимает вопрос о психологии познания мира конкретным человеком. В  этом процессе  мы неизбежно сталкиваемся  с неясными вопросами, которые непонятны именно нам, а всем другим вроде бы понятны (или они делают вид, что им это понятно). И здесь можно определить два подхода.

(1) Мы останавливаемся перед проблемой и дальше не идем - такой вариант можно назвать  тупиковым.  (2) Мы обозначаем проблему как "черный ящик" и допускаем ее правильность без обязательного для себя понимания - и идем дальше. Этот путь намного предпочтительней, так как не задерживает нас, не вызывает комплексы, не разделяет нас с окружающим миром. В дальнейшем мы можем вернуться к "черным ящикам" и, наконец, понять, в чем там дело. Но мне приходилось встречаться с людьми, которые требовали абсолютного понимания здесь и сейчас и которые его не получали, что оказало  влияние на дальнейшее становление их личности.

В школьные годы "непонятности" встречались мне достаточно часто. Например, мне непонятна была проверка гласных О/Е/Ё: какого - синего, темнеть - тёмный. Но я была послушной,  и  мне хотелось, чтобы "шкрабы" на меня не шипели, а любили  меня и ставили в пример. Но потом я вернулась к "черным ящикам" и теперь могу объяснить себе и другим, как связана между собой тройка этих гласных.